# VBA Excel: How can I send an image saved in Excel on my hard drive in an email?

Tags: image, vba, excel, email

I have some code that copies cells from Excel, pastes them as a picture, saves the picture, and then sends an email with that picture in it's body. The problem is that because the image gets saved on my hard drive, when it gets sent out to the recipients cannot see the image. Is there a way  of getting around this?

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Email()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim Location As String
Dim RecipientNumber As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim PrimaryRecipients As String
Dim SecondaryRecipients As String
Dim To_Name As String



Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
Range("A2").Select

While ActiveCell <> "" And ActiveCell <> "0"

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     RecipientNumber = ActiveCell.Value
     To_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
     If To_Name = "" Or To_Name = "0" Then
         To_Name = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value


     Worksheets("Output 2").Activate
     Range("C2").Value = RecipientNumber 

     Dim objChart As Chart
     Call ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M28").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)
     Sheets.Add.Name = "Without Formatting"
     Worksheets("Without Formatting").Shapes.AddChart
     Worksheets("Without Formatting").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Select
     Set objChart = ActiveChart
     objChart.Paste

     With ActiveChart.Parent
      .Height = 300 ' resize
      .Width = 750  ' resize
      .Top = 100    ' reposition
      .Left = 100   ' reposition
      End With

      Dim DayForLocation As String
      Dim MonthForLocation As String
      Dim YearForLocation As String
      Dim DateForLocation As String
      DayForLocation = Day(Now)
      MonthForLocation = Month(Now)
      YearForLocation = Year(Now)
      DateForLocation = YearForLocation & MonthForLocation & DayForLocation

      Dim FileLocation As String
      FileLocation = "C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\" & DateForLocation

      If Dir("C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\" & DateForLocation) <> "" Then
          MkDir ("C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\" & DateForLocation)
      End If
      FileLocation = FileLocation & RecipientNumber & ".jpeg"
      objChart.Export (FileLocation)

      Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:M28").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
      If rng Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
                 vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
          Exit Sub
      End If

      'Keep_Format

      With objMail
         .To = PrimaryRecipients
         .Cc = SecondaryRecipients
         .Subject = "Information: " & RecipientNumber & " Updated Profiler"

         Dim Greeting As String
         If Time >= #12:00:00 PM# Then
             Greeting = "Afternoon"
         Else
             Greeting = "Morning"
         End If

         Dim LastMonth As String
         LastMonth = MonthName((Month(Date)) - 1)

         Dim InsertImage As String
         InsertImage = "<img src='" & FileLocation & "'>"

         .HTMLBODY = "<font face=Arial><p>" & "Good " & Greeting & " " & To_Name & "," & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
        ' .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + RangetoHTML(rng)
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + InsertImage
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Kind Regards" & "<br>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<img src='C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\test.jpg'>"
         .Send
       End With
       Worksheets("Contacts").Activate
       Application.DisplayAlerts = False
       Sheets("Without Formatting").Delete
       Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Wend

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing

Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing


End Sub
```

This is quite an issue, can someone please help?

Comment: Add the file as an attachment and change the image source to the image file only: `<img src='test.jpg'>`.

Comment: But I want the image to be in the body of the email so that it is seen when the email is opened, rather than as an attachment

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these two lines I changed / added are better than the two lines of comment above to illustrate what I mean:

```
 With objMail
         .To = PrimaryRecipients
         .Cc = SecondaryRecipients
         .Subject = "Information: " & RecipientNumber & " Updated Profiler"

         Dim Greeting As String
         If Time >= #12:00:00 PM# Then
             Greeting = "Afternoon"
         Else
             Greeting = "Morning"
         End If

         Dim LastMonth As String
         LastMonth = MonthName((Month(Date)) - 1)

         Dim InsertImage As String
         InsertImage = "<img src='" & FileLocation & "'>"

         .HTMLBODY = "<font face=Arial><p>" & "Good " & Greeting & " " & To_Name & "," & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Email text." & "</p>"
        ' .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + RangetoHTML(rng)
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + InsertImage
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<p>" & "Kind Regards" & "<br>"
         .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\test.jpg"
         .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<img src='test.jpg'>"
         .Send
       End With
```

The only thing I actually changed is this:

```
 .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\test.jpg"
 .HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<img src='test.jpg'>"
```

You'll note that you don't see test.jpg as an attachment anymore but rather directly displayed in the body of the email.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that still has the same issue. It does not come up as an attachment (which is good) but in the email I don't see the image but the "image cannot be displayed" icon

Comment: Then there might be a problem with your Outlook. The code works perfectly fine for. Actually, I am using this already for years now and have used it at multiple international corporations (even in a Citrix server-farm setup). Make sure you have switched in Outlook the HTML-View on. Also, some international setups require two quotation marks `""` instead of one apostrophe `'`. This would yield `.HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<img src=""test.jpg"">"`. Other than that there is nothing I can think of.

Comment: I've tried this and it still isn't working, it's worth noting that if I just use the line `.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\asfadsf\Documents\test.jpg"1` and comment the line below out then I get the image attached, but if I uncomment the line below and use both it is not attached or shown.

Comment: In this case you might want to continue trouble shooting using this line `.HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + "<img src=""test.jpg"" alt=""The picture is attached but cannot be displayed in the body of this email."">"`. This website might be able to help you do some more trouble shooting. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp

Comment: I now get the image attached and the same icon below, but no alternative text

Comment: Sounds like a typo. Are there any special characters in the name of the picture? Are there leading white spaces in the name of the file? Make sure that the file name is **exactly** the same within the source tags. You can also add a leading `.\ ` to the source like so: `.HTMLBODY = .HTMLBODY + " <img src="".\test.jpg"">" `.

Comment: It is exactly the same, to be sure I have even copied and pasted the name from the attachment line which works but it still doesn't work

Comment: Create in Outlook an email with a picture in it (as you intend to do it). Then go into the VBE for Outlook at in the `direct window` type `? ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLbody`. Then Outlook will show you want it wants / expects as HTML source code to show the attachment within the body of the email. Sometimes it is `? ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1).HTMLbody` instead.

Comment: Sorry for being a pain, but I haven't really used VBA in outlook much before. Can you please explain to me where to put the code `? ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.HTMLbody` and how I can get there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88023/discussion-between-ralph-and-benjs-1).