# Add signature and clipboard image to email body VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an Outlook message through VBA, in which I want to add an string of text, some tables (using a RangetoHTML function), a picture and then the mail signature.

I wish to avoid saving a file with the picture and adding it through an attachment (more often than not it doesn't display the image correctly), i.e. using the command:

`img src= 'img_name'.jpg`

I was hoping it could be done using the following code but, so far, I can't get the image to be placed after the text and before the signature:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

    'Variables
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    Dim s As String
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Get the text that will go on the mail body
    s = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2").Range("A1")
    Set r1 = Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:D4")

    With OutMail
        Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

        .To = "example@test.com"
        .Subject = "test"
        .HTMLbody = s & RangetoHTML(r1) & .HTMLbody

        'Set the range that will be pasted as an image
        Set r2 = Sheets("Plan1").Range("A5:D9")
        r2.CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture
        OutMail.Display

        'Set the position to paste the image
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = currentPosition
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.End = wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start

        'Paste the image
        wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paste
        .Close olSave

    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

1. If I use the command `wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = currentPosition` the image goes before the text;
2. Same if I place the command `.SendKeys "{END}"` just before `wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = currentPosition`;
3. And if I use `wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = Len(.Body)` the image is placed after the signature!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if I understand, but maybe something like `Application.Paragraphs.Add().Paste` before `OutMail.Display` (I think the signature is added when it's displayed)

Comment: If you don't add the picture as an attachment to the email then the email will not contain the picture and the picture cannot be shown (as it is not part of the email). The **only** other way is to upload the picture to a server (which will be available to the recipient) and include a link to the picture on said server to the email. To attach the picture to the email use the following solution / code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223633/vba-excel-how-can-i-send-an-image-saved-in-excel-on-my-hard-drive-in-an-email/32224724#32224724

Comment: Note that (in the above provided solution) Outlook neglects to show the attached picture as an attachment just because the picture is shown in the email body. Yet, this is just Outlooks deranged way of showing things. Other email clients will show the picture (correctly) as an attachment. Otherwise, the picture couldn't be shown in the email body. Reading through the VBA code you will also note that the picture gets actually attached to the email. Yet again, Outlook will not show the picture as such (for whichever reason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to find a workaround, just by making some adjustments to my code:

```
Sub Mail_Selection_Range_Outlook_Body()

'Variables
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim s1 As String
Dim s2 As String
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'Get the text that will go on the mail body
s1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2").Range("A1")
s2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Plan2").Range("A2")
Set r1 = Sheets("Plan1").Range("A1:D4")

With OutMail
    Set wordDoc = OutMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    .To = "example@test.com"
    .Subject = "test"
    .HTMLbody = s1 & RangetoHTML(r1) & .HTMLbody

    'Set the range that will be pasted as an image
    Set r2 = Sheets("Plan1").Range("A5:J22")
    r2.CopyPicture Format:=xlPicture
    OutMail.Display

    'Set the position to paste the image
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start = currentPosition
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.End = wordDoc.Application.Selection.Start

    'Paste the image
    wordDoc.Application.Selection.Paste

    .HTMLbody = s2 & .HTMLbody

    .Close olSave

End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This way I'm still able to avoid pasting the image through an attachment.

Note: in order to place the text that goes after the picture in a new line, I just add a `"<br>"` before the text inside the reference cell (in this case, "A1" of "Plan2").